# Is the use of the infinitive more correct than gerund in this sentence?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

In one of the lines in The Blacklist,

> I need your assistance **locating** the source of a call that was placed
>   on a pay phone.

For some reason, the sound of the infinitive feels more natural to me.

> I need your assistance to locate the source of a call that was placed
>   on a pay phone

Are they both correct? And is one use more correct than the other?

Comment: I'd use the gerund most of the time, personally. Both are correct, though.

Comment: Is there a reason for your preference to use the gerund over the infinitive? Because the infinitive here sounds more natural to me.

Comment: I guess the reason for my preference is that the gerund sounds (a bit) more natural to me. :)

Comment: One sentence cannot be more or less correct than another.

Comment: My observation has been that non-native speakers are much more likely to use an infinitive when a gerund would be better than the other way around. I don't know if that helps, but it might just help you to weight your instincts a bit.

But one sentence may sound more natural than the other. I (native RP speaker) feel the first is more natural than the second.